# Magento Custom Options: Trying to adjust the layout of options

Tags: html, css, magento, drop-down-menu, themes

I'm trying to get the options to be under each other and not side by side

http://www.acuity-sports.com/baseball/field-equipment/fencing-windscreens/250-fence-crown-poly-cap.html

I'm trying to find out what code I need to fix and for some reason my brain is dead on this one.

Do I need to adjusted the `product-options-wrapper`

Comment: I thought it was a very basic Magento Question asking what part of the code needs to be adjusted to get the two "custom option" fields to stack on top of each other and not side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the code in my theme.css

Had to change:

```
#product-options-wrapper.product-options dd { border: none; display: inline-block; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;
```

Had to increase the `margin-right: 100px`